# get Updated Value in bundle of AlertDialog everytime

Tags: android, bundle, android-alertdialog

i want to pass data from one dialog to another.
i have a onCreateContextMenu dialog to show options on listview

**Code:**

```
   @Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
            .getMenuInfo();

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case R.id.update_item:

        Object o1 = lv1.getItemAtPosition(info.position);
        ItemDetails obj_itemDetails1 = (ItemDetails) o1;
        /*Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "You have chosen : " + " " + obj_itemDetails1.getId(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  */
        Bundle arg= new Bundle();
        arg.putString("key", obj_itemDetails1.getId());
        showDialog(DIALOG_ID, arg);
        return true;

    }
    return false;
}
```

I am sending data from this dialog to Alert Dialog using Bundle .

**Code:**

```
   protected final Dialog onCreateDialog(final int id, Bundle arg) {
    Dialog dialog = null;
    switch (id) {
    case DIALOG_ID:
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
              arg.getString("key");// getting same value here

        builder.setMessage(arg.getString("key"));
        builder.setPositiveButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   dialog.cancel();
               }
           });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Update", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

               }
           });    

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.setTitle("Update Info");
        dialog = alert;
        break;

    default:

    }
    return dialog;
}

 }
```

from

```
Bundle arg= new Bundle();
            arg.putString("key", obj_itemDetails1.getId());
            showDialog(DIALOG_ID, arg);
```

i am sending new data everytime according to selected position

but in `arg.getString("key");` in Alert Dialog i am getting same data everytime. Data is not updated even if i clicked a new position.

i have used `arg.remove("key");` and `arg.clear();` but they didn't work.

How can i achieve this. or any other idea to pass data in AlertDialog.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the `showDialog` method as it's deprecated, also if you check the javadoc you'll see:

> A call to onCreateDialog(int, Bundle) will be made with the same id the **first time this is called for a given id**.

So you can't update that value like that.

--

Using DialogFragment you could just search the Dialog (or create it if it doesn't exists) and pass the new parameter through a method:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
YourDialog d = YourDialog.newInstance(...);
d.show(ft, YourDialog.class.getSimpleName());
```

then search for it:

```
YourDialog d = (YourDialog) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(YourDialog.class.getSimpleName())
if (d == null) {
    //create a new dialog like before
}

d.setValue(yourValue)
```